# Pseudo Random Weighted Numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, statistics

How can I generate *n* random integers at *i* interval having a bias placed on a number if is not picked after a duration of *t* time?

Comment: By numbers do you mean integers?  And is there a bounded range of possible values?

Comment: You will need to record every number generated

Comment: I'm not a maths student, what is a _bias_ on a number? Can you give an example?

Comment: Tim, I bias means that as intervals elaps the odds of a number that has not yet been selected increase.

Comment: since this is placed in statistics, do you need to actually calculate it or would an approximation be enough? My question is do you just need to know how probable a certain event sequence is? If so you should be able to solve the issue mathematical and then simply translate it into code rather than trying to solve it deterministic.

Comment: I see you still haven't figured out the solution to your issue ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518450/pseudo-random-drug-screening-with-weighted-bias-as-time-goes-by

Comment: Well, describe to us how you would do it in real life. For example: suppose you had ten different colours of marbles. You put a hundred of each in a big jar and shake the jar.  Now you start pulling out marbles at random. Every time you pull out a blue marble, the chances of getting a blue marble the next time are lower. The colour that has been pulled most often is the one least likely to be chosen, and the one that has been pulled least often is the most likely to be chosen. There are *infinitely many* processes that match your incredibly vague description, so we have nothing to go on here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code won't compile, but you get the gist of the algorithm I have in place. It might not be particularly efficient, but it gets the job done and you will have to tailor it to your needs. Namely the variables `n`, `timer` (create a timer), `timerTicks` and the method `ChooseRandomNumber`.

```
int maxNumber = n;
timer timer;
Dictionary<int, int> numbers
int timerTicks;

// Set up numbers with 0 base rating
SetUpDetails()
{
  timer.interval = i
  for (int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++)
    numbers.Add(i, 0);
}

timer.Tick
{
  // List with numbers
  List<int> numbersToChooseFrom;
  foreach (KeyValuePair number in numbers)
  {
    // Must be added at least once
    numbersToChooseFrom.Add(number.Key)
    if (number.Value > timerTicks)
      for (int i = 0; i < (number.Value/timerTicks); i++
        // i.e. if number hasnt been chosen for 
        // timerTicks iterations give it more weight
        numbersToChooseFrom.Add(number.Key) 

    // Some numbers occur more than once and thus have greater chance
    int choice = ChooseRandomNumber(between 0 and numbersToChooseFrom.Length)
    int RandomNumber = numbersToChooseFrom.ElementAt(choice)
    return RandomNumber;
  }
}
```